# 401 on Traefik dashboard > Health because of Basic Auth HTTP?

Tags: docker-swarm, traefik

I try to run traefik (using docker & swarm) and protect the dashboard using a basic auth http like this:

```
traefik:
  image: traefik:v1.7
  deploy:
    # ...
    labels:
      - traefik.frontend.rule=Host:foo.bar.baz
      - traefik.enable=true
      - traefik.port=8080
      - traefik.redirectorservice.frontend.entryPoints=http
      - traefik.redirectorservice.frontend.redirect.entryPoint=https
      - traefik.webservice.frontend.entryPoints=https
      - traefik.frontend.auth.basic.users=user:password
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  command: >
    --docker
    # -...
    --api
    --api.statistics.recenterrors=25
```

It work great, but when I am on **HEALTH** (on foo.bar.baz/dashboard/status) I see thoses 401 (from Traefik himself):

[image]

Any idea how to fix this properly ?
Thanks

PS: for more details: https://community.containo.us/t/401-on-traefik-dashboard-health-because-of-basic-auth-http/826